# How to setup printing in cocoa, swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, printing

I have made printing functionality for custom NSView of NSPopover by the assigning the following action to button for this NSView in mainController:

```
@IBOutlet var plasmidMapIBOutlet: PlasmidMapView!

@IBAction func actionPrintfMap(sender: AnyObject)
{
    plasmidMapIBOutlet.print(sender)
}
```

It is working, but the print window has no option for **Paper Size** and **Orientation**, see screenshot below.
 [image]

1. What should I do to get these options in the print window?
2. And, how to make the NSView fitting to the printable area? Now it is not fitting.

I have figured out some moments, but not completely. So, I can setup the printing by the following code

```
 @IBAction func actionPrintMap(sender: AnyObject)
 {
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo()
    let operation: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: plasmidMapIBOutlet, printInfo: printInfo)
    operation.printPanel.options = NSPrintPanelOptions.ShowsPaperSize
    operation.printPanel.options = NSPrintPanelOptions.ShowsOrientation
    operation.runOperation()

    //plasmidMapIBOutlet.print(sender)
 }
```

But, I still have problem. From the code above I can get **only** orientation (the last, ShowsOrientation), but not both PaperSize and Orientation. How can I manage both ShowsPaperSize and ShowsOrientation?

Comment: Did you read [Printing Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000083-SW1)?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, I have updated the questions. Now I can have one, but not both ShowsPaperSize and ShowsOrientation options. How can I have both?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have found the answer which is simple to write but it is not really obvious from apple documentation.

```
    operation.printPanel.options.insert(NSPrintPanelOptions.showsPaperSize)
    operation.printPanel.options.insert(NSPrintPanelOptions.showsOrientation)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the code originally posted is that `options` is being assigned twice, so the first value assigned, `ShowsPaperSize` is overwritten by the value `ShowsOrientation`. That's why you only see the `ShowsOrientation` option in the dialog.

By using multiple `insert` operations, you are adding options rather than overwriting each time. You can also do it this way which I think reads better:

```
operation.printPanel.options.insert([.showsPaperSize, .showsOrientation])
```

And finally, it also works to "set" the options, and by supplying the existing options as the first array value, you achieve the affect of appending:

```
operation.printPanel.options = [
    operation.printPanel.options,
    .showsPaperSize,
    .showsOrientation
]
```

(The first array element `operation.printPanel.options` means that the old options are supplied in the list of new options.)